# My collision list does not work as expected

Tags: c#, xna

CollisionTest(); doesn't work like expected.. Only one box have a collision...
This code will probably hurts your eyes and its may be a bad way to do what i want

**Game1.cs**

```
Texture2D boxTexture;
GameObject box, box1, box2;
List <GameObject> boxlist;
Random rand = new Random();

LoadContent()
   boxTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("box");
   for(int i = 0; i < boxlist.Count; i++)
            boxlist[i] = new GameObject(boxTexture, new Vector2(rand.Next(100, 1200), rand.Next(500, 600)));

Update()
    CollisionTest();

public void CollisionTest()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < boxlist.Count; i++)
    {
        if (player.collisionRect.Intersects(boxlist[i].collisionRect))
        {
            ground.Y = boxlist[i].collisionRect.Y;
            player.setPositionY(0);
        }
        else
        {
            ground.Y = 640;
       }
    }

}

Draw()
for (int i = 0; i < boxlist.Count; i++)
    boxlist[i].Draw(spriteBatch);
```

**GameObject.cs**

```
public Rectangle collisionRect
{
    get
    {
        return new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y, texture.Width, texture.Height);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < boxlist.Count; i++)
{
    if (player.collisionRect.Intersects(boxlist[i].collisionRect))
    {
        ground.Y = boxlist[i].collisionRect.Y;
        player.setPositionY(0);
    }
    else
    {
        ground.Y = 640;
    }
}
```

It's only working on the last box in the list because you keep executing the "else" code on all boxes, even after a collision has been detected.

Let's say you detected a collision on the first box. You execute your "on collision" code. Then for the next box, you don't collide. You execute your "on no collision" code. Since you're setting `ground.Y` to different values for both conditions, you will only see the result of the last check.

The correct method would be something like this:

```
bool collided = false;
for (int i = 0; i < boxlist.Count; i++)
{
    if (player.collisionRect.Intersects(boxlist[i].collisionRect))
    {
        ground.Y = boxlist[i].collisionRect.Y;
        player.setPositionY(0);
        collided = true;
        //break; //If you want to only handle one collision you can uncomment this
    }
}
if (!collided)
    ground.Y = 640;
```